# Get files size from txt with url lines

Tags: php, file, url, size

I want to know how i can get file size from url lines inside a txt, then return obtained file sizes to a single txt. I have found this code but i don't manage to output all the sizes into a single txt file.

```
function getRemoteFilesize($url, $formatSize = true)
{
    $head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($url, 1));
    // content-length of download (in bytes), read from Content-Length: field
    $clen = isset($head['content-length']) ? $head['content-length'] : 0;
    // cannot retrieve file size, return "-1"
    if (!$clen) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (!$formatSize) {
        return $clen; // return size in bytes
    }
    $size = $clen;
    switch ($clen) {
        case $clen < 1024:
            $size = $clen .' B'; break;
        case $clen < 1048576:
            $size = round($clen / 1024, 2) .' KiB'; break;
        case $clen < 1073741824:
            $size = round($clen / 1048576, 2) . ' MiB'; break;
        case $clen < 1099511627776:
            $size = round($clen / 1073741824, 2) . ' GiB'; break;
    }
    return $size; // return formatted size
}
$url = 'url_here';
echo getRemoteFilesize($url); // echoes "7.51 MiB"
```

Comment: Nothing here attempts to write to a file.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "then return obtained file sizes to a single txt". Is this question about how to write a txt file? If yes, strip down your example to this problem (since it seems the code here works OK).

Comment: Can we assume (since your question is a big vague), that you have a list of URLs, one per line in a text file?  And you want to run getRemoteFilesize on each URL from that text file?  Well read the file, loop on each line, call getRemoteFilesize for each and send the results to your output file.  The output file must be openned first, written to, then closed.